# How can I trim / replace the first character in a FileStream in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have the following code for a series of file drawdowns using IDHttp.Get, the contents of the files

```
procedure Tform1.GetData;
{***************************}

var
        fs2 : tfilestream;
        s : char;
begin
        Sleep(1000);
        idhttp1.HandleRedirects := TRUE;
        fsjson2 := tfilestream.Create((GstrPath+GstrRep+'-'+GstrHome+'.json'),fmcreate);;
        idhttp1.IOHandler := idssl;
        IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
        IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
        try
                idhttp1.Get(GstrURL,fs2);
        except
                on E: Exception do
                begin
                        rememo1.Lines.Add('Seems to be an issue, trying again...');
                        Sleep(500);
                        idhttp1.Get(GstrURL,fs2);
                end;

        end;
```

I would like there to be a method of either trimming the first character although I don't think this is possible, or replacing the first character (which comes with the info by default) with a blank character. I think it's a little out of my skillset at the moment to do, and so would appreciate any help someone can give.

Thanks

Ant

Comment: Why don't you use `TIdHTTP.Get` [invariant that returns string](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdCustomHTTP_Get@string.html)? You could discard the first character and save the rest to a file. Is the stream returned in the response too long?

Comment: What is this first character anyway? You are probably retrieving JSON. There should be no need to discard any characters from it. It seems like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) so far.

Comment: You'd need to know how the text was encoded. Exactly how best to solve your problem likely depends on what you do next with the stream. I also think it plausible that you have misdiagnosed your problem. That's always a risk when you ask about your solution without stating the problem. Your exception handling is totally flawed, the sleeps are bogus, and I suspect you have leaks.

Comment: Why don't you just tell us why you think you need to strip off the first character and let us help

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be to simply derive a new class from TFileStream and override its Write() method to ignore the first char written to it, and then pass all subsequent chars to the base class. But why do you want/need to ignore the first char? Since you are downloading JSON, is the first char a BOM, by chance? Why would you want to throw that away when saving the JSON to a file?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions:

You are receiving data into a stream. If you want to trim the first character, you could, at the place you handle the stream, skip reading the first character and throw it away.

If you have no control on where the receiving stream is handled, then you may simply create a new stream and loop reading all characters from the receiving stream and write them into the destination stream. Then throw away the received stream and keep the one you created.

If the data received (currently the stream) is not too big, you could receive it into a string instead of a stream, then you can trim/delete/insert anything with simple string manipulation, and finally write the modified string back to a stream for later use.